# can we use Engle-Granger test for cointegration when I have lags of dependent variable as explanatory variable in my model?

Tags: cointegration

I want to check for cointegration test using Engle-Granger test for my model which is of the form:
 y= y(-1) + y(-2) + x1 + x2 + x3

Is Engle granger test suitable for such cases.

Comment: In principle, I do not see a problem with doing that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you suggest any book or any such work where they have done so. Actually, my instructor is not convinced. I need to have an explanation for this.

Comment: I may try later. (I would post a complete answer if I had time.)

Comment: Whatever you model, why don't you apply the standard Engle-Granger test? [Here](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ582/cointegrationtestingandestimatingslides.pdf) is a great lecture note by Eric Zivot. Or do you want to alter the standard E-G test by changing the equation somehow in the first stage of the test procedure? (I don't know what would happen to the distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis then. But why would you do that?)

Comment: Leave the lags out if you want to perform the Engle-Granger test as your estimates will be super consistent anyways. However, you cannot say anything about the significance of the estimates. If you want to test cointegration in a dynamically well specified single-equation model then use the ADL or unrestricted ECM models

Comment: @Plissken actually, the model doesnot show cointegration when specified without lags.When specified with lags its showing cointegration as per EG test.

Comment: I think that what you are using could correspond to the leads-and-lags cointegration estimator, check Saikkonen, P., (1991), Asymptotically efficient estimation of cointegration regressions. Econometric Theory, 7. If I remember well, it was shown to have better finie-sample properties. You might want to check there how to carry the cointegration test, in particular whether you need different p values.

Comment: If you want to apply the Engle-Granger method you should leave out the lags. Remember that the static regression can be interpreted as an equilibrium relationship! If you want to include lags then you can use a more efficient framework such as the ADL model or unrestricted ECM model. Look at Co-integration, Error Correction, and the Econometric Analysis of Non-Stationary Data by Banerjee et. al or Time-Series-Based Econometrics: Unit Roots and Co-integrations by Hatanaka.